# jquery val() implementation

Tags: jquery, dom, selenium

I have a dyamically loaded form that has to be "prefilled" with some data. By prefilled I mean that a `select option`  or a `input type="radiobutton"` have to be preselected.

Of course, I'm using jQuery...

I am confused because I expected `.val()` function to add attribute `selected="selected"` to an `option` element but it doesn't.

How does it work then? It changes something in the DOM, but I couldn't find that change in Firebug...

Normally, I wouldn't care about the details, but I was playing with Selenium tests and wanted to make a test that checks if a `select option` is preselected as expected and since it doesn't set `selected="selected"` I was wondering how to test it?

Answer (score 0):

use attr:

.attr("selected", "selected")

or

```
<script>

    $("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .trigger('change');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new jquery `.prop` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)) functionality to set or test for properties on an element.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it work then?

Here is the source code:

```
jQuery(elem).find("option").each(function() {
    this.selected = jQuery.inArray( jQuery(this).val(), values ) >= 0;
});
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/255460e4836e86b86f48dd5b7d2a2cbf3f996de2/src/attributes.js#L273

Above, `this` is the `option` dom node, so you were close. It sets the `selected` property, instead of the `selected` attribute.